# Changing branches seems to delete a file

Tags: git

I clone a repo from our git server, then checkout a tracked branch followed by git status; git indicates a file is deleted. No work was done in the repo, only git commands in the this order:

```
git clone <myrepo>
git branch - indicates on master branch
git status - reports working directory is clean
git checkout <release-branch>
git status - shows a file has been deleted
```

Doing an `ls <file>` fails, indicates the file really is deleted.
gitk shows the red node indicating local uncommitted changes, but no changes were made in the repo, just a checkout to the branch. The parent commit has the file when looking at the tree in gitk.
`git checkout -- <file>` brings the file back.

However if I clone the same repo, but include the branch, then do a status, the file is present:

```
git clone -b <release-branch> <myrepo>
git status - reports working directory is clean
ls <file> - shows file exists
```

This is repeatable by several different people on different systems.

Why did changing branches cause this file to be deleted?

Here is the full command line sequence and output (names changed to protect the innocent):

```
$ rm -rf test-*

$ git clone <repo> test-master
Cloning into 'test-master'...
remote: Counting objects: 11478, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5918/5918), done.
remote: Total 11478 (delta 7856), reused 8429 (delta 5558)
Receiving objects: 100% (11478/11478), 7.48 MiB | 183 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7856/7856), done.

$ cd test-master

$ git branch
* master

$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git checkout relbranch
Checking out files: 100% (112/112), done.
Branch relbranch set up to track remote branch relbranch from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'relbranch'

$ git status
# On branch relbranch
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    prtbatt.c
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ cd ..

$ git clone -b relbranch <repo> test-relbranch
Cloning into 'test-relbranch'...
remote: Counting objects: 11478, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5918/5918), done.
remote: Total 11478 (delta 7856), reused 8429 (delta 5558)
Receiving objects: 100% (11478/11478), 7.48 MiB | 178 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7856/7856), done.

$ cd test-relbranch

$ git branch
* relbranch

$ git status
# On branch relbranch
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is deleting the file behind your back? Git should not do that. Thinking… what system are you using Git on? Maybe the file-system is case-insensitive which is causing problem, when two versions of a file exist with different capitalization.

Comment: No scripts are running. The only hook we have emails the team when a push is done to selected branches. I am in a cygwin shell on Windows 7. There is no sister file with different case letters.

Comment: Can you paste the exact output? Replace filenames if you'd like. In particular, that last `git status`, but the whole thing couldn't hurt.

Comment: The command line sequence is too long to post in a comment. I hope it is not bad etiquette to answer my own question to add more information, but that is the only way I know to get the requested present in context.

Comment: @Scot: You can always edit your question and add the missing information. Just click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11691372/edit) link below it.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question with the full info.

Comment: Do you have a .gitignore file in master that isn't in relbranch, or is .gitignore different between the two?

Comment: What happens if you call `git checkout master && git status` in your `test-relbranch` directory? And possibly `git checkout relbranch && git status` afterwards.

Comment: @Christopher: verified the .gitignore file is the same in both repos.

Comment: @knittl: thanks for the idea; in the test-relbranch repo clone directory `git checkout master && git status` shows a clean repo, but `git checkout relbranch && git status` now shows that the prtbatt.c file has been deleted. So the problem seems to be in switching from the master branch to my relbranch branch. Its like my index some how got push to my central repo and gets loaded when I switch branches. Please remember I started this test with rm -rf test-* and have made no edits or file deletes at all in this testing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out someone created the file twice on two different branches, without merging (yes necessary public floggings have taken place), and in one case used all uppercase letters and on the other branch used all lowercase letters. Once they realized the mistake, they deleted one of files and merged, then went on vacation. But they did the delete from Windows, which isn't case sensitive. When they did a merge, it got ride of both copies. After returning from vacation they couldn't find the file on their branch and this lead to figure out what was going on. After recreating the file and merging out, everything is fine.